# Two Foreign keys issue django

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

Hi I have this python code for django, and basically i am trying to build it so that every tourobject can have many tourbets but also i want to be able to save a certain winning tourbet as current bet but then django complains that it can't find TourBet

```
 class TourObject(models.Model):
    tourplace = models.ForeignKey(TourPlace, related_name='tourplace', verbose_name="tourplace", default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=155, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Status")
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=datetime.now)
    current_bet = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    next_bet = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    no_auction_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=1)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("tourobjects:tourobject", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

class RelatedTourObject(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(RelatedTourObject, self).get_queryset().select_related('tourobject').all()

class TourBet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='tourbet', verbose_name='User')
    tourobject = models.ForeignKey(TourObject, related_name='tourobjectbet', verbose_name="tourobjectbet", default=1)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=datetime.now)
    bet_amount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=1)

    objects = models.Manager()
    related_tourobject = RelatedTourObject()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.bet_amount)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this.

```
class TourObject(models.Model):
    winning_bet = models.ForeignKey('TourBet', related_name='winning_bet')
```

Comment: Thank you Bipul, i added it there and also had to add related_name since it was conflicting. Cheers for that

Comment: Great, Updated my answer. Gotta upvote or  accept for support #SOreadytohelp. :)